# System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filename, contents) writes double data value in scientific notation

Tags: file, text

I have .net application and it reads data from the database and write to another text file. For writing "Double" value it is writing in scientific notation which is not desirable. 
For example -0.00005 is being written as -5E-05, but -0.00045 is being written fine. What is the problem occuring here I don't understand. Is there any restriction after decimal point with "zero" values?

Please some one answer me ASAP.

Regards,
Mostafa

Comment: I think you need to create a http://www.sscce.org/ to ensure you're not doing something weird.  Should take only a moment.  Then [edit] and post the relevant code with an example taken right from the debugger, before and after.

Comment: Hi, Mostafa. When writing to the text file, you are probably implicitly casting your Double to a string and the default output is in scientific notation. You can explicitly do this casting instead with the ToString method of Double and provide instructions on formatting. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94.aspx